# php and preg_match: how to capture data in mult line html?

Tags: php, regex

The goal is to capture Paris
whci is included between

```
<th>City :</th><td>(.)*</td>
```

Here is the  source  I have

```
                <tr>
                    <th>postal code :</th>
                    <td>75012</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <th>City :</th>
                    <td>Paris</td>
                </tr>
```

I tried with

```
/<th>City :</th><td>(.)*</td>/gmi
```

expression with no luck. Any idea ?

Comment: /<th>City :<\/th><td>(.)*<\/td>/gis

Comment: [Don't parse HTML with regex!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/418066)

Answer (score 2):

You have a few problems to deal with here.

1. PHP does not support the `g` (global) modifier and the `m` (multi-line) modifier causes `^` and `$` to match the begin/end of each line. You can remove these, we don't need them.
2. You need to account for whitespace between the `th` and `td` elements.
3. You are repeating the capturing group `(.)*` so only the last iteration will be captured, in this case the letter `s` in Paris would be captured instead of the entire contents of that `td` element.

For this simple case, the following would be enough:

```
~<th>City :</th>\s*<td>(.*?)</td>~i
```

**Note:** The `*` operator follows the dot `.` saying match any character except newline "zero or more" times. When supplying the question mark after the operator `*?` you're telling the engine to return a non-[**greedy**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#greedytrap) match.

However, for parsing HTML in the near future I would recommend using a tool such as [`DOM`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php).

```
$dom = DOMDocument::loadHTML('
     <tr>
      <th>postal code :</th>
      <td>75012</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <th>City :</th>
      <td>Paris</td>
     </tr>
');
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
$td = $xp->query('//th[contains(.,"City")]/following-sibling::*[1]');
echo $td->item(0)->nodeValue; //=> "Paris"
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to enable dotall modifier and put `.*?` in-between the `</th>` and `<td>` tags, so that it would match the existing newline character. And also you need to put the `*` inside the capturing group or otherwise it would capture the last character in the string `Paris`

```
<th>City :</th>.*?<td>(.*?)</td>
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/aW6sZ2/1)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe slower but easier for broadly using: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php